# Auto Increment Alphanumeric ID

Tags: sql

Hope I can have some help here.  I have the following stored procedure which will generate alphanumeric ID by inserting the first alphabet from @NAME..  i.e.  `@name = Test` will produce.  T001.  But I am trying to include the first 2 aplha..  i.e, `@name = Test` to produce.  TE001.  I have tried changing `@PREFIX VARCHAR(2)`, and ..`SUBSTRING(@NAME, 1,2)`  but when I do this.  The numbers will not auto increase..

```
DECLARE @NEWID VARCHAR(5);
DECLARE @PREFIX VARCHAR(1);
SET @PREFIX = UPPER(SUBSTRING(@NAME, 1, 1))
SELECT @NEWID = (@PREFIX + replicate('0', 3 - len(CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.OID + 1))) +       CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.OID + 1)) FROM (
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(T.TID) IS null then 0 else MAX(T.TID) end as OID FROM (
SELECT SUBSTRING(ID, 1, 1) as PRE_FIX,SUBSTRING(ID, 2, LEN(ID)) as TID FROM Testing
) AS T WHERE T.PRE_FIX = @PREFIX
) AS N
```

Comment: Hope you're not using this as a primary key for anything because you will end up with duplicate values unless this is a single-user database, or you are explicitly locking the table for the entire transaction :)

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work:-

```
DECLARE @NEWID VARCHAR(5);
DECLARE @PREFIX VARCHAR(2);
SET @PREFIX = UPPER(SUBSTRING(@NAME, 1, 2))
SELECT @NEWID = (@PREFIX + replicate('0', 3 - len(CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.OID + 1))) +       CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.OID + 1)) FROM (
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(T.TID) IS null then 0 else MAX(T.TID) end as OID FROM (
SELECT SUBSTRING(ID, 1, 2) as PRE_FIX,SUBSTRING(ID, 2, LEN(ID)) as TID FROM Testing
) AS T WHERE T.PRE_FIX = @PREFIX
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @NEWID VARCHAR(5);
DECLARE @PREFIX VARCHAR(2);
SET @PREFIX = UPPER(SUBSTRING(@NAME, 1, 2))
SELECT @NEWID = (@PREFIX + REPLICATE('0', 3 - LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, N.OID + 1))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.OID + 1)) 
FROM (
      SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(T.TID) IS NULL
                  THEN 0
                  ELSE MAX(T.TID) END AS OID 
      FROM (
            SELECT SUBSTRING(ID, 1, 2) AS PRE_FIX, SUBSTRING(ID, 3, LEN(ID)) AS TID 
            FROM Testing
            ) AS T 
      WHERE T.PRE_FIX = @PREFIX
      ) AS N
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fe7a/2/0)